# Recovery Password Generation

Tags: iphone, ios, password-recovery, forgot-password

During the testing of our app, it was observed that there was no functionality to get inside the application if user forgets his password.

On discovering this we implemented a password generation technique as follows
1. Create a specific string using user information.
2. Apply SHA1 on the string
3. Take some part of the SHA1 hash as a password

Above algorithm is applied both at server side and device side. So that they do not need to have any interaction. So if the user forgets his password, he can request the server. Server runs the algorithm as above and send the generated password to users email. On device side same password is generated using the same alto. So when user enters it, it matches and user is given access.

Somehow I am not satisfied with this because we are using same string to generate password. So every time user forgets password and generates it, he will get the same password which is not how password generators work.

So I was thinking of adding some more to string which will be variable, but will be same both at server and device side. One of the option is using date in string, but if the server is in different time zone device and server will generate different passwords.

Are there any better solutions to this? please suggest ...

Comment: This algorithm breaks [Kerckoffs's principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerckhoffs's_principle). Though not directly equivalent, I believe it applies. Essentially, any encryption method (or in this case password storage) should not rely on the algorithm being secret to be secure. If I know the algorithm, then I can attempt to calculate a user's password.

Comment: Can you please provide some solution then?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to use "Hash-based message authentication code" ([HMAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code)).  The idea behind this is that even in a plain-text connection the user's password is not visible as the username, password and a server-generated "session key" are used to generate a hash that changes whenever the session key changes.  Given the hash is one-way, it's impossible to derived the user's password from the hash sent over the network connection.

There is nothing new under the sun.

Comment: Did not follow much :( could you please try to put it in different words? I have also gone through the link that you have given, but it seems that it also will generate same password all the time.